# Writing methods for Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods, reverse

I know it must be easy but I have to ask. How can I write a method for this I made it wrong but I couldn't find it. The code is about reverse an array using a method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
       int i;
       int size;
       int array[] = new int[50];
       Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the size of the array");
       size= read.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter Array Numbers : ");
       for(i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
           array[i] = read.nextInt();
       }

   }
    public static int arrayReverse(int array[]){
    int size;  
        for(int i = 0; i < size/ 2; i++){

         int c = array[i];
          array[i] = array[size - i - 1];
          array [size - i - 1]  = c;
         }

      for(int k:array)
        System.out.print(k + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You never give `size` a value in `arrayReverse()`.

Comment: To start `size` is useless. You're going to get an `index out of range` error if you input a size >50.

Comment: actually it didn't give this error. Actually I made the reverse thing without using method but I have to use method for my project .

Comment: @Ekin, what Francisco is trying to say is that if the user inputs a value higher than 50 when asked the size of the array you will have an ArrayOutOfBounds error

Comment: Lets just assume user give below 50, my mistake is to put all of this in a simple method and i am just begginer so I dont know the complicated things so if you can just help me with this

Comment: @Ekin What exactly is your second function trying to accomplish? Are you trying to invert the array ie. [1,2,3,4,5] --> [5,4,3,2,1]?

Comment: yes this is what i want to accomplish

Comment: @Ekin `int size; for(int i = 0; i < size/ 2; i++)` What is the value of `size`?

Comment: Actually my question for my project is : Create a method that takes one parameter as integer array, and prints all the elements of the array in reverse order.

Comment: @Biffen when you write a size number after the "enter the size of the array" we get the size number then we can use it later

Comment: @Ekin Nope. That's a different variable called `size`. It exists in a different scope.

Comment: @Ekin … And if all you want to do is *print* the array in reverse order there's no need to reverse the contents of the array itself.

Comment: @Biffen how can i change it then because i want to use same size value

Comment: @Ekin How do you usually get a value from one method to another? (Although in this case you actually already have the value there, you just need to get it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you just want to print the `array` in reverse order. You can do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    int size;

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the array");
    size = read.nextInt();
    int array[] = new int[size];//Set the size of the array when you definetely know it
    System.out.print("Enter Array Numbers : ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = read.nextInt();
    }
    for(int j = size-1; j >= 0; j--){
        System.out.println(array[j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: but it goes to infinite

Comment: sry edited the code. Had to change `size--` to `j--`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable in global and static, or pass it as argument to the function arrayReverse, or in the function arrayReverse do `int size = array[].length;`

Answer (score 0):

The size in the main method may not be initialized in the arrayReverse method: The local variable size may not have been initialized. And the arrayreverse must return a result of int.

Answer (score -1):

You're function would want to look a bit like this.

```
public static int[] arrayReverse(int[] arr) {
    int size = arr.length;
    int invertedArr[] = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        inverterArr[i] = arr[size-1-i];
    }
    return invertedArr;
}
```

Although note. With the first function you provided to get `arr`. The size of `arr` will always be 50. Since you force it to be 50 every time. So if you decide `size` to be 5 and you input the digits `[1,2,3,4,5]` in to `arr`. `arr` will actually be `[1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,....,0]`. So the first 5 digits followed by 45 zeroes. I'd recommend you do the following:

```
int size = read.nextInt();
int array[] = new int[size];
```

Comment: invertedArr[] = new int[size];     it says this is not a statement

Comment: @Ekin missed a variable declaration, fixed it now.